# What is acct_dimension_display in openbravo?

Tags: openbravo

what is acct_dimension_display in openbravo? Sales order window is having Cost center field and it has display logic like @ACCT_DIMENSION_DISPLAY@. So what is the meaning of @ACCT_DIMENSION_DISPLAY@ ?
  Please give solution.

Answer (score 0):

Openbravo have various dimensions and it's configurable under General Ledger Configuration.
http://wiki.openbravo.com/wiki/General_Ledger_Configuration
According to dimension configurations,these fiels will get enabled.

(i.e) Once Cost center dimension got enabled,you can able to see cost center fields

Answer (score 0):

I was having the similar issue, I followed following steps:

1. Navigate to Window: Client,
2. Under **Accounting Dimension**, Mark the field: **Cost Center**. Two more fields(Header, Line) will show up. Select any one based on requirement.
3. Log out and log in again.

Cost center field start showing up on Transaction windows.

ACCT_DIMENSION_DISPLAY is variable which checks the flag is marked for account dimensions in Window: Client.